# bootstrap clearfix on ajax content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

```js
if($('h4#rankText-'+i).text().length > 'The Shawshank Redemption ('.length){
            $('h4#rankText-' + (i+1)).parent().after('<div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>');
        }
```

I am getting data through ajax and show it in columns and rows.
So I have two columns and every element inside these columns have h4 heading but when this **heading gets bigger, the element below that gets messed up.**
In the above code, I am checking if rankText-i has text bigger than certain string then apply clearfix below its next element so that the next row below it doesn't get messed up. But it doesn't seem to work.
What am i doing wrong? Is there a better fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can try set width, max-width for h4 tags and use css text-overflow

```
    h4 {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

More detail:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp